# PHP proxy called twice

Tags: php, mp3

I am serving MP3 files through a PHP script so I have some form of security over them.
I am running some SQL statements to track the streams/downloads, then altering the headers and outputting the MP3.

Simplified version of my code here:

```
// do some SQL work
if(file_exists($file)){

    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
}
```

The script is called from various sources including from an iPhone application.
Regardless of what calls it via a URL it always gets executed twice and I can;t figure out why.

I have even added a mail function to it to see when it is called and every time the script is executed I get two emails!

Have googled the life out of it and can't find anyone with the same issue so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The code provided doesn't contain the bug you are talking about.  Please provide the full source.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey There is not much more of it, just some SQL statements that have no relevance.

Comment: Almost certainly it's a bad rewrite, or bad client-side code causing two requests to be issued. nothing in this code could cause that.